# Replace “&lt;” and “&gt;”and "&lt;\" with “<” ,“>” and </ in sql server

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, sql-server-2016

I know that Replace `&lt;` and `&gt;` with `<` and `>` in sql server has been asked at

[Replace “&lt;” and “&gt;” with “<” and “>” in sql server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17503725/replace-lt-and-gt-with-and-in-sql-server)

but I need to expand upon it.  I am trying to create formatted HTML code from a MS 2016 SQL server.

What I have is:

```sql
DECLARE @json nvarchar(max) = (SELECT DISTINCT AU2.PMID, 
SUBSTRING(
(
 SELECT ', '+  CASE WHEN AU1.Format IS Not Null Then +'<b>' + 
 AU1.LastName+ ' ' + AU1.Initials + '</' + AU1.Format + '>' ELSE
 AU1.LastName + ' ' + AU1.Initials END   AS [text()]
 FROM dbo.[Publication.PubMed.Author] AU1
 WHERE AU1.PMID = AU2.PMID
 ORDER BY AU1.PmPubsAuthorID
 FOR XML PATH ('')
), 3, 1000) + '. Journal Name ' [Authors]
FROM dbo.[Publication.PubMed.Author] AU2
WHERE AU2.[PMID] =27702896   FOR JSON AUTO)

SELECT @json
```

And what I get back is:

```
Name DG, Name K, Name A, Chen FK, Song X, Pirun M, Santiago PM, Kim-Kiselak C, Platt JT, Lee E, Hodges E, &lt;b&gt;Rosebrock AP&lt;/b&gt;, Bronson RT, Socci ND, Hannon GJ, Jacks T, Varmus H Journal Name
```

If I try to put TYPE into the

```sql
FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
```

I get an error saying:

> Argument data type xml is invalid for argument 1 of substring function.

I've tried to add `REPLACE`

```sql
replace(CASE WHEN AU1.Format IS Not Null Then +'<b>' + 
AU1.LastName+ ' ' + AU1.Initials + '</b>' ELSE
AU1.LastName + ' ' + AU1.Initials END,  '&lt;', '<')
```

But then I get an error

> The xml data type cannot be selected as DISTINCT because it is not comparable.

The best that I can come up with is:

```sql
SET @json = replace(@json, '&lt;\', '<')
SET @json = replace(@json, '&lt;', '<')
SET @json = replace(@json, '&gt;', '>')
```

Just before the final `SELECT @json`.

I will have over a 1000 records that I need to pull. Do I need to do this is steps?

Based upon TT code I changed mine to

```
         DECLARE @json nvarchar(max) = (SELECT DISTINCT AU2.PMID, 
        SUBSTRING(
    (
        SELECT ', '+  CASE WHEN AU1.Format IS Not Null Then +'<b>' + 
         AU1.LastName+ ' ' + AU1.Initials + '</b>' ELSE
         AU1.LastName + ' ' + AU1.Initials END   AS [text()]
        FROM dbo.[Publication.PubMed.Author] AU1
        WHERE AU1.PMID = AU2.PMID
        ORDER BY AU1.PmPubsAuthorID
        FOR XML PATH (''),TYPE).value('.[1]','NVARCHAR(MAX)'
    ), 1, 1000) + '. Journal Name ' [Authors]
      FROM dbo.[Publication.PubMed.Author] AU2
     WHERE AU2.[PMID] =27702896   FOR JSON AUTO)
```

And that woks fine. but see comment below

Comment: For what it's worth I would have the SQL return the raw query result and do the json/xml conversion as needed in the client. SQL is not a natural fit for this sort of manipulation.

Comment: Too many conditions to determine how to format.  I have nightly processes that make changes to the output.  If this than this and if this then that- I did it client side when it was in a desktop app and sometimes it would take 2+min to produce the report.  Way too long.  Needs to be almost instant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can tell you are on the right track with `FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE`. It's just that you then have an XML text value which you need to convert to a string (i.e. of type `[N]VARCHAR(X)`). This can be done with the [XML `value()` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/xml/value-method-xml-data-type).

An example ([fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/2f0ff/6)):

```sql
CREATE TABLE t(s NVARCHAR(16));
INSERT INTO t(s)VALUES(N'1'),(N'2'),(N'3'),(N'4'),(N'5'),(N'6');

SELECT
  (
    SELECT N'<b>'+s+N'</b>'
    FROM t
    FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE
   ).value('.[1]','NVARCHAR(MAX)');
```

results in

```xml
<b>1</b><b>2</b><b>3</b><b>4</b><b>5</b><b>6</b>
```

Comment: My closing bold tag looks like <\/b> it seems to format but it looks strange with the extra \ in the tag.  I have '<b>' + AU1.LastName+ ' ' + AU1.Initials + '</b>'

Comment: @user1314159 That is required for JSON formatting, the forward slash is escaped with a backslash. When you parse the data back in any setting (say Java) you should get the proper HTML.